# Nifi ConvertAvroToJSON--Number types error

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying to read data from 'Oracle' and populate the same to 'mysql' database.

```
'ExecuteSQL' - >'ConvertAvroToJSON' - >'ConvertJSONToSQL' - >'PutSQL'
```

[image]

:

Figure 1 shows the unconverted data in ConvertAvroToJSON.

[image]

Figure 2 shows the data after the conversion.

[image]

The data type after conversion is now in the wrong format.

Comment: please edit your question and provide the `create` sql command for your source table.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with ConvertJsonToAvro and ConverAvroToJson processors and I often have collided with some strange warnings or errors. E.g. ConvertJsonToAvro can show you warning like "Could not parse incoming data" and that's all. Nothing else.

After that I have been starting to use ConvertRecord Processor. I need to convert json to avro, so I set JsonTreeReader in Reader property and AvroRecordSetWriter in Writer property.

My advice: try to use ConvertRecord processor. Maybe you will see more detailed information about parsing and errors.